# Exporting JSON of Timestamp intervals from firestore- Typescript Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to create a class of points in time with 15 minute intervals (every of them located in a timeframe between 2 timestamps from firestore). I am importing timestamps from firestore using:

```js
export class Interval {
    sentTimestampStart: firebase.firestore.TimestampStart;
    sentTimestampEnd: firebase.firestore.TimestampEnd;
}
```

I would like program to get start timestamp, and end timestamp. Later it should set 15  minute intervals in timeframe. Intervals should be in JSON.

I am a beginner, I have already searched through many possible solutions but they don't work. I highly appreciate any possible solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share the code you're getting the timestamps from Firestore and outputting it to a JSON to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)